# Help with actions in EventHandler

Tags: dynamic, string-manipulation, eventhandler, logic

I am trying to write a program where the user types on the keyboard in a specified location, and Mathematica outputs what you are currently typing, plus a prediction that is updated in real time of what you are going to type next. I have done everything I thought I had to do, and it is working partially in that the variable labeled "oracle" is updated dynamically, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the prediction to update. Can anyone help me or give advice?

```
EventHandler["click mouse here and type",
{{"KeyDown", "a"} :> {human = StringJoin[human, "a"],
 guess = StringJoin[guess, oracle]},
 {"KeyDown", "f"} :> {human = StringJoin[human, "f"], 
  Dynamic[guess = StringJoin[guess, oracle]]}
  }]

Dynamic[human]
Dynamic[guess]
```

The rest of the code works as I expect, and gives the correct value as I type. The problem is that every time I type in a new letter to update the "human" input slot, the "guess" output slot stays blank. The guess is supposed to update every time I push the "a" or "f" key, by adding the oracle/prediction to the end of the guess string.

```
analysis[input_, n_] := 
  If[StringLength[input] >= n && ! (StringLength[input] == 0 ) ,
  Tally[StringPartition[input, n, 1]],{}]

(*This lists all the substrings of length 'n' of the input, 
 and tallies how much each substring occurs*) 

Dynamic[
  tree = 
    Table[
      If[! analysis[human, n] == {}, SortBy[analysis[human, n], Last], {}], 
      {n, 1, 5}]]

Dynamic[
   branch = 
     Table[
       Select[
         tree[[n]], 
         StringTake[#[[1]], n - 1] == StringTake[human, -n + 1] &], 
       {n, 1, 5}]]

Dynamic[
   oracle =
     If[! branch[[5]] == {}, StringTake[First[Last[branch[[5]]]], -1],
      If[! branch[[4]] == {}, StringTake[First[Last[branch[[4]]]], -1],
        If[! branch[[3]] == {}, StringTake[First[Last[branch[[3]]]], -1],
          If[! branch[[2]] == {}, StringTake[First[Last[branch[[2]]]], -1],
            If[! branch[[1]] == {}, StringTake[First[Last[branch[[1]]]], -1],
              "a"]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand your code. There are too many syntax errors and undefined variables -- it has no chance of running. Further, you show little understanding of the `Dynamic` front-end expression wrapper.

However, I want to do more than just scold you, so here is some code that implements an extremely simple event handler that actually works.

Simple oracle -- it guesses the next character is the one that has been typed the most in the past.

```
oracle[] :=
  Module[{acnt, fcnt},
    {acnt, fcnt} = {StringCount[human, "a"], StringCount[human, "f"]};
    If[acnt > fcnt, "a", "f"]]
```

Up-dater -- makes the event handler more succinct.

```
update[chr_] :=
  (human = human <> chr;
   guess = guess <> oracle[];
   text = text <> chr)

human = ""; 
guess = "";
prompt = "click mouse here and type:";
text = "";
EventHandler[Dynamic[prompt <> text],
  {{"KeyDown", "a"} :> update["a"],
   {"KeyDown", "f"} :> update["f"]}]
```

> `click mouse here and type:aaaafffaaafffffaaaafff`

```
Dynamic[human]
Dynamic[guess]
```

> `aaaafffaaafffffaaaafff`
>   `aaaaaaaaaaaaafffaaaaaf`